# type traits for result of operator overloaded for different ref-qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, type-traits

So basically I am writing a template for determining the type of an expression (in this case the dereference operator):

```
template<class T>
struct Asgard {

  template <class T>
  static auto check(T) -> decltype(*std::declval<T>()); // <-- the important line

  static utils::tt::SubstFailure check(...);

  using Dereference = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));

};
```

but after seeing an example on the net which did it slightly different ([here](https://docs.google.com/a/isocpp.org/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDIyMDc3NjUwMTczOTM0Mjk3NjABMDI2MzM3MjkxNDM4NDQ5MzE4NDcBLWVsS1Y4dFhtdDhKATQBaXNvY3BwLm9yZwF2Mg)):

```
template<class X>
static auto check(const X& x) -> decltype(x == x); // other operator, but not important.
```

it got me thinking what about if the operator is overloaded for different qualifiers of the object so I created a test class:

```
struct ThorsChariot {
  std::integral_constant<int, 1> operator*() const &{
    return std::integral_constant<int, 1>();
  }
  std::integral_constant<int, 2> operator*() & {
    return std::integral_constant<int, 2>();
  }
  std::integral_constant<int, 3> operator*() const &&{
    return std::integral_constant<int, 3>();
  }
  std::integral_constant<int, 4> operator*() && {
    return std::integral_constant<int, 4>();
  }  
};
```

The following notations I use basically mean:

```
1 — the return type of a call on — const &
2                                  &
3                                  const &&
4                                  &&
```

And here is what I tested:

```
Asgard<const ThorsChariot>::Dereference
Asgard<ThorsChariot>::Dereference

Asgard<const ThorsChariot &>::Dereference
Asgard<ThorsChariot &>::Dereference

Asgard<const ThorsChariot &&>::Dereference
Asgard<ThorsChariot &&>::Dereference
```

I think that these types should be (in order) (I use `n` as a shortcut for `integral_constant<int, n>` (see above note about notation)):

```
1 2  1 2  3 4
```

And here are the results for different attempts:

```
(A)
static auto check(T) -> decltype(*std::declval<T>()); 
4 4  4 4  4 4

(B)
static auto check(T t) -> decltype(*t);
2 2  2 2  2 2

(C)
static auto check(const T &t) -> decltype(*t);
1 1  1 1  1 1

(D)
static auto check(T &&t) -> decltype(*t);
1 2  1 2  1 2

(E)
static auto check(T &&t) -> decltype(*std::forward<T>(t));
static auto check(T &&) -> decltype(*std::declval<T>());
3 4 1 2 3 4
```

(C) and (D) I understand. (A) and (B) give strange results to me.
The closest I got was using perfect forwarding (E). They work for lvalue and rvalue types, however for a non reference type it gives the return of a call on rvalues. Why is this?
Is there a way I can obtain the results I want? Is what I want correct?

*I know that a an operator returning different types for different qualifiers is not only extremely rare, but probably a bad practice, but this doesn’t mean I don’t have to understand the behaviour I observed.*

Comment: BY the way, you could just write `return {};`...

Comment: @KerrekSB thank you, I was wondering if there is a shorter way for that

Answer (score 2):

What you need is

```
(E)
static auto check(T &&t) -> decltype(*std::forward<T>(t));
```

and **drop**

```
Asgard<const ThorsChariot>::Dereference
Asgard<ThorsChariot>::Dereference
```

from your tests, because they don't make sense (meaning, they are equivalent to the corresponding rvalue references). This leaves you with `1 2 3 4`, which is exactly the result of the four remaining tests.

Keep in mind that [`std::declval<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) always adds a `&&` reference to `T`, so what you get is an rvalue reference, unless `T` is an lvalue reference, in which case you also get an lvalue reference. The same thing happens with [`std::forward<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward):

```
template< class T >
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();

template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t );

template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t );
```

By the way, your test is a bit more complex than necessary. You can pass `T` as a *template parameter* from `Dereference` to `check`, which then uses `std::declval<T>()` directly, so you don't need `std::forward<T>()`:

```
template<class T>
struct Asgard {

  template <class T>
  static auto check(int) -> decltype(*std::declval<T>()); // <-- the important line

  template <class T>
  static utils::tt::SubstFailure check(...);

  using Dereference = decltype(check<T>(0));

};
```

(I think the `int` parameter is not needed either, but I am not testing now).

Now,

> returning different types for different qualifiers

may be rare now, but I find it *good* practice and I think will be more frequent in the future. Look at [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) for instance, which may be a non-member function, but could be equally a member function (it is not for technical reasons like having to write the `template` keyword). Members `begin()`, `end()` in STL containers are not like that (yet), and I don't know if and when they will be, but I am sure this would be the right way.

I always ignore the case of `const&&` because I have never seen a use that makes sense, and I think I recall reading Stroustrup saying the same thing. The idea of rvalue references is exactly to be able to *modify* a temporary object (which makes sense because this object may hold pointers or references to actual data). So there seems to be no use of `const&&` where `const&` wouldn't do exactly the same.

On the other extreme, one could also consider the `volatile` qualifier for completeness, which gives four more combinations, raising the total to eight, and that's all. But this is even more rare.

Comment: could you elaborate on why `Asgard<ThorsChariot>::Dereference` doesn’t make sense? Isn’t that the same as saying `Asgard<int *>::Dereference` doesn’t make sense?

Comment: I agree on `const&&`. I just added it for symetry

Comment: @bolov It doesn't make sense because `&&` is added by `std::declval` anyway, as I am explaining. So you get exactly the same result as with `Asgard<ThorsChariot&&>::Dereference`.

Comment: I was thinking from an interface point of view: shouldn’t `Asgard<ThorsChariot>::Dereference` should be the type of dereferencing a lvalue and not the type of dereferencing a rvalue?

Comment: @bolov Look at the [reference collapsing rules](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html): `T` + `&&` gives `T&&`, and `T&` + `&&` gives `T&`. If you add `&` as you say, then you *always* get an lvalue reference and you have no way of specifying an rvalue reference. "lvalue always wins".

Comment: sry I am beeing such a nuisance. I understand (I think) the basics of reference collapsing rules and that `std::forward<T>` gives `T &&`, but let’s forget for a second about the implementation of the trait and that is uses `std::forward` and look at the trait like a black-box. Let’s say that we have a type `T` that behaves differently when the object is non-temporary and when the object is temporary (rvalue) (as `ThorsCahriot`). Wouldn’t you want `Trait<T>` to describe the behaviour of a non-temporary object instead of the behaviour of a temporary one?

Comment: @bolov Maybe, maybe not. But the rules are there now. If you insist on your own rules, you have to represent them in your own way instead of relying on the language. E.g. interpret `T` as `T&` and `rvalue<T>` as `std::remove_reference<T>::type&&`, where `rvalue` is just a class template serving as placeholder for rvalues. But I think that while doing this you will probably change your mind.